# Not returning the answer i need

Tags: scheme

```
(define (checksum-2 ls)
  (if (null? ls) 
      0
      (let ([n 0])
        (+ (+ n 1))(* n (car ls))(checksum-2 (cdr ls)))))
```

Ok, I have this code, its suppose to, if I wrote it right, the number (n) should increase by one every time it goes through the list, so n (in reality) should be like 1 2 3 4, but I want n to be multiplied by the car of the list.

Everything loads, but when the answer is returned I get 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you format your code differently, you might have an easier time seeing what is going on:

```
(define (checksum-2 ls)
  (if (null? ls) 
      0
      (let ([n 0])
        (+ (+ n 1))
        (* n (car ls))
        (checksum-2 (cdr ls)))))
```

Inside the `let` form, the expressions are evaluated in sequence but you're not using the results for any of them (except the last one). The results of the addition and multiplication are simply discarded.

What you need to do in this case is define a *new* helper function that uses an accumulator and performs the recursive call. I'm going to guess this is homework or a learning exercise, so I'm not going to give away the complete answer.

**UPDATE**: As a demonstration of the sort of thing you might need to do, here is a similar function in  Scheme to sum the integers from `1` to `n`:

```
(define (sum n)
  (define (sum-helper n a)
    (if (<= n 0)
        a
        (sum-helper (- n 1) (+ a n))))
  (sum-helper n 0))
```

You should be able to use a similar framework to implement your `checksum-2` function.

Comment: Well you see, I don't know how to go about doing that. What I don't get is why is my function ignoring the math and just returning 0?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the results of the arithmetic calculations. The only thing your `checksum-2` function can ever return is either `0`, or whatever `(checksum-2 (cdr ls))` returns. So ultimately it always returns `0`.

Comment: So what needs to be changed? Like I've been at this for hours and I'm not getting anywhere. It's something with the recursive call?

Comment: Ok thanks, umm we'll try to figure it out from the demonstration edit, but what we don't get is why does ours just return 0. Our math algorithm makes sense to us but it just doesn't run. :(

Comment: I have explained, twice, why your implementation returns 0. You might have to go back and review some introductory Scheme material if you're having trouble understanding that part.

Comment: I honestly don't even know why we are learning scheme, its pointless to me because I need to know more java in the field I'm going into. but Thanks for your help I guess.

Comment: @DwayneR.Fortune You don't know how lucky you are to be learning Scheme. I was a Java programmer before I learned Scheme. Learning Scheme (by reading the book [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Interpretation-Computer-Electrical-Engineering/dp/0262510871/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1348648731&sr=8-1)) was the first time I felt I was *really* learning about programming. If you want to write monkey code for some corporation, by all means just learn Java. If you want to open your eyes a bit, learn Scheme (and then Python, Haskell, Scala, Prolog...)

Comment: So far in the 2 almost 2.5 years of college I've learned C++, Java, COBOL, SQL, and currently learning some jython. I just find it harder to think in scheme since I've learned all those other ways to program.